# τ = r × F, In unity3d/PhysX how do we define r?

Tags: unity, physics, mathematics, physx, torque

How does PhysX define/calculate the distance from the center of mass where we apply the force to produce a torque?

Comment: In response to what event? A collision? The point of contact would make an intuitive point to compute the radius from in that case, no? Or is there another case you have in mind?

Comment: when using the addtorque function  https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you are applying the torque.

- The [AddTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) method (by default) interprets the `Vector3` parameter as a torque in world space. That means the engine does not need to compute a radius at all: it's already baked into the value you pass as input (ie. the argument is already a product of force times distance, measured in Newton-metres).

  So if I call `body.AddTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, 1))`, this could be interpreted as a force of 1N in the world y+ direction applied to a point 1m from the center of mass along the world x+ axis:

  $$\tau = \begin{bmatrix}1m \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1N \\ 0\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1Nm\end{bmatrix}$$

  ...or as a force of 10 N in the x+ direction applied 0.1 m from the center of mass along the world y- axis:

  $$\tau = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -0.1m \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}10N \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1Nm\end{bmatrix}$$

  Either way, the net torque and the resulting rotation is the same. So the radius exists only in your interpretation, or in the calculations you do to determine the torque you want to apply when forming your argument to pass.

  This is also the case if you use `ForceMode.Force` as the second parameter (here the naming is misleading, but the documentation page linked above explains how to interpret it in this case). You can also use other modes to interpret the `Vector3` argument differently:

  - `ForceMode.Acceleration` treats the input as an angular acceleration, measured in \$\frac {^\circ} {s^2}\$.  This acts over the course of one simulation step and ignores the mass of the body.
  - `ForceMode.Impulse` treats the input as an instantaneous change in angular momentum, measured in \$\frac {kg \cdot m} {s}\$. This ignores the length of the simulation step and is affected by the mass of the body (heavier bodies will rotate less, given the same impulse).
  - `ForceMode.VelocityChange` treats the input as an instantaneous change in angular velocity, measured in \$\frac {^\circ} {s}\$. This acts ignores both the length of the simulation step and the body's mass, similar to modifying `body.angularVelocity` directly.

  [AddRelativeTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html) is similar, except that the input is given in the body's local coordinate system, rather than the world coordinate system.

  For completeness, other methods act as follows...
- The [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) method applies the force through the center of mass, so no torque results from using this method.
- The [AddForceAtPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html) method applies the force through the point you provide in world space, so the radius is the distance between that point and the center of mass.

  [AddRelativeForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) is similar, except that the input is given in the body's local coordinate system, rather than the world coordinate system.
- In the case of a collision, the radius is the distance of the point of contact from the center of mass.